# android - Persist a pending intent in Notification

Tags: android, push-notification

I need a persistent notification, so I'm  using the `.setOngoing(true)` attribute. I need this notification there until the user make some action.

Everything fine, but my notification, after click on it, lost the notification's `ContentIntent` and still there but without any action on it.

Is there any possibily to persist this `setContentIntent` after clicked?

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "after click on it on time" means, what "lost the pending intent" means, and what "still there but without any action on it" means. A `PendingIntent` cannot be persisted, if you mean saving it to disk.

Comment: @CommonsWare "lost the pending intent" means: After clicked in my notification, it lost the `ContentIntent` action